# Celery beat is sending due tasks but the tasks are not getting executed

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, django-celery-beat

Problem statement: The celery beat is sending the scheduled task on time. But the worker is not able to receive the task and execute it.

I am using the following celery version

```
django-celery-beat==2.2.0
celery==4.4.0
django-celery==3.3.0
```

The command is being used for celery-beat

```
celery -A project_path.dev beat -l info --scheduler django_celery_beat.schedulers:DatabaseScheduler
```

The command is being used for celery-worker

```
celery worker -A project_path.dev --pool=solo -Q celery -l info
```

task.py

```py
@periodic_task(run_every=(crontab(minute='*/30')),
               options={'queue': settings.CELERY_QUEUES_DICT["celery-periodic"]})
def celery_task():
    print("Executing Task")
```

celery-beat logs:

```
[2022-07-03 23:00:00,501: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task path.to.celery_task (path.to.celery_task)
```

celery-dev logs:

```
[tasks]
  . path.to.celery_task
```

I see a couple of other tasks are not getting executed. Can I get some help here to understand the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your worker command `-Q celery` specified the worker only process tasks in queue **celery**. But the queue in your task definition is `settings.CELERY_QUEUES_DICT["celery-periodic"]`. You should check whether they are pointed to the same queue

Comment: Hello. Yes `settings.CELERY_QUEUES_DICT["celery-periodic"]` this refers to the same queue.

Comment: Can you give the detail logs of scheduler and workers? Including [config] and [queues]

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The mentioned queue had around 120k pending messages to get processed. Hence this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

print function doesn't work in celery, you should use:

```py
logger.info("Executing Task")
```

instead of:

```py
print("Executing Task")
```